# no sound for mp3 and no sound for movies

Tags: sound

I am using ubuntu 14 and the sound comes out of my speakers when i go into sound on settings but it wont play mp3 or sound in movies. The sound card seems to be working but I was fooling about with ardour and that might have something to do with it

Comment: Do you have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed? Without that, you can't decode and play mp3 and other non-open media formats.

Answer (score 0):

Try with VLC media player.
To install VLC Player use the following command:

> sudo apt-get install vlc

Answer (score -1):

Try blow command

```
Sudo apt-get update

Sudo apt-get install

Sudo apt get install vlc
```

Use vlc player